# Correct syntax for User-Agent Grouping in Robots.txt: Is it "understood" by ALL crawlers as of 2018?

Tags: syntax, web-crawler, user-agent, robots.txt

In order to save space with over 200 user-agents in robots.txt I've GROUPED the user-agents. My question here is not weather or not the user-agents will *respect* the directive, but rather weather or not all user-agents will *understand* this shorter and much more elegant way of writing robots.txt (PS for convenience sake I've shortened the list from over 200 bots to merely 10 to make the question more to the point).

```
# ALLOW
User-agent: bingbot
User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: Baiduspider
User-agent: DuckDuckBot
User-agent: Pinterest
Allow: /
Sitemap: https://www.website.org/sitemap.xml

# DISALLOW
User-agent: UbiCrawler
User-agent: Zealbot
User-agent: SiteSnagger
User-agent: WebStripper
User-agent: WebCopier
disallow: /
```

Comment: 1) There are countless crawlers. 2) Most of them don’t list what parts of the robots.txt spec they support, they just say "we support robots.txt". -- So every crawler would have to be tested in experiments. I would say that’s practically impossible. -- Usually you would author your robots.txt according to the spec, and expect crawlers to parse the robots.txt according to the spec … I mean, that’s one purpose of these specs in the first place, that we don’t have to cater for every individual implementation, right?

Comment: If saving space is your goal, get rid of the section that explicitly allows crawling for bingbot, googlebot, etc. They will crawl you unless you tell them not to.

Comment: @plasticinsect thanks/upvoted your suggestion, can you please add your suggestion as answer? which part can be deleted exactly? 1) Must I add a wildcard `User-agent: *` as replacemenbt of that first list or just delete everything including the `Allow: /` ?